# 10 seconds to be allowed <him to do so>

Tags: sentence-construction

> Rules
>
> 4. If either man falls through weakness or otherwise, he must get up unassisted, **10 seconds to be allowed him to do so**, the other man meanwhile to return to his corner, and when the fallen man is on his legs the round is to be resumed and continued until the three minutes have expired.
>    [['Marquess of Queensberry Rules'-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquess_of_Queensberry_Rules)]

Could you help me rewrite the noun phrase "10 seconds to be allowed him to do so" as a declarative sentence? (Like: ...allow...him to do so)

It seems that both "10 seconds" and "him" are the objects of "allow". But I'm really confused about the construction of the noun phrase.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more modern, clear way of writing that phrase, perhaps as a parenthetical (in parentheses or between em dashes) would be:

> he is to be allowed 10 seconds to do so

The manner of speaking in the original quote is quite antiquated (unsurprising, since the rules you're quoting were written in the 1860s), and would likely be considered incorrect by modern standards.

Comment: @JunweiGuo that has a somewhat different meaning.  "[is to be](https://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/be-to-verb-are-to-get)" is used to talk about what *will happen* in the future, in a way that gives a command to the referee reading the rules.

Comment: A.He is to be allowed 10 seconds to do so.
B.Passengers are allowed one item of hand luggage each.
Is "allowed" used the same way in A and B?

Comment: @JunweiGuo Yes, I'd say so.